# Parsing through misaligned columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have source data that comes in a raw csv with misaligned columns, some without certain columns at all. The desired data can be located in any of 1-30 columns. The main key to find where data lies is that "1 Yr Cost" is present in the header of every sub-frame.

Example source data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

sourceCSV = """col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
,,Cost,1 Mn Cost,1 Yr Cost,,
,Michigan,$50 ,$55 ,$65 ,,
,,,,Cost,1 Mn Cost,1 Yr Cost
,,,Indiana,$40 ,$45 ,$55 
,Cost,1 Mn Cost,1 Yr Cost,,,
New York,$25 ,$30 ,$35 ,,,
,,Cost,1 Yr Cost,,,
,Florida,$10 ,$20 ,,,"""

csvStringIO = StringIO(sourceCSV)
dfSource = pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep=",", header=None)
```

| col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | Cost | 1 Mn Cost | 1 Yr Cost | null | null |
| null | Michigan | 50 | 55 | 65 | null | null |
| null | null | null | null | Cost | 1 Mn Cost | 1 Yr Cost |
| null | null | null | Indiana | 40 | 45 | 55 |
| null | Cost | 1 Mn Cost | 1 Yr Cost | null | null | null |
| New York | 25 | 30 | 35 | null | null | null |
| null | null | Cost | 1 Yr Cost | null | null | null |
| null | Florida | 10 | 20 | null | null | null |

I need to parse through the data and get data in a format similar to the below:

| Location | Cost | 1 Mn Cost | 1 Yr Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michigan | $50 | $55 | $65 |
| Indiana | $40 | $45 | $55 |
| New York | $25 | $30 | $35 |
| Florida | $10 | null | $20 |

The only thing I can figure out is to manually looping through each column, but this is very inefficient. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that works in the particular case:

- consider odd rows as headers, even ones as data
- add "Location" in the first cell
- stack to remove NaNs
- reshape

```
dfSource = pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep=",", skiprows=1, header=None)

(dfSource[0].where(dfSource.index%2==1, 'Location').to_frame()
  .join(dfSource.iloc[:, 1:]) 
  .set_index([dfSource.index//2, dfSource.index%2])
  .stack().droplevel(-1).to_frame('value')
  .pipe(lambda d: d.set_index(d.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(), append=True))
  .unstack(1).droplevel(1)['value']
  .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
)
```

Output:

```
0 1 Mn Cost 1 Yr Cost  Cost  Location
0      $55       $65   $50   Michigan
1      $45       $55   $40    Indiana
2      $30       $35   $25   New York
3       NaN      $20   $10    Florida
```

Answer (score 0):

The malformed dataset has some "alignment" in that is the rows containing the needed columns and values are pairwised, except for *location* values which has leftward offset and needs to be captured separately.
Start loading csv with skipping the 1st row of those unneeded `col0     col1    col2 ....`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep=",", header=None, skiprows=1)
```

Then, we go with a short processing (grouping rows and collect columns and values separately):

```
def f(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=['Location'] + x.iloc[0].dropna().tolist(),
                        data=[x.iloc[-1].dropna().values])

res_df = df.groupby((df == 'Cost').any(axis=1).cumsum()).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   Location  Cost 1 Mn Cost 1 Yr Cost
0  Michigan  $50       $55       $65 
1   Indiana  $40       $45       $55 
2  New York  $25       $30       $35 
3   Florida  $10        NaN      $20
```